# ATSAMD21 doesn't seem to start, device not found/detected

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, atmel-studio, atsamc21, atmel-ice

I just finished assembling my PCB with an ATSAMD21G18A and was super thrilled to flash it with my program. Sadly Atmel Studio tells me that it can't find the device.

I tried to debug the whole thing, but I still don't have it working. I think I'm missing something.

What I have:

- I can read the target voltage in Atmel studio, and it seems to be
  good (3.3v)
- I can measure VDD_Core at ~1.2V, which is nominal.
- I can measure the SWDIO and SWCLK signals on the JTAG (presumably
  sent from the Atmel ICE)
- I double checked that the JTAG is connected to the SAM connector and not the AVR connector (did that mistake before)
- The power supply is showing about 2mA current draw. (not a lot, isn't it)

What i'm missing:

- Somehow the external clock doesn't start to swing. I don't know what
  the default setting is, if it should start to swing with a unflashed
  uC or not.  I can't read the Device ID or read from flash in Atmel
- Studio (Error: Device not found).

The clock not swinging is my biggest worry, but the ATSAM should have an internal clock to work on, right?

The program I'm trying to flash is a example code for the SAMD21 eval board (LED_TOGGLE).

Do you have any idea why the uC might not be working? I have to admit, that this is the first time I've tested this PCB, so it might as well be another issue.

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

Comment: Please upload a higher resolution image of your schematic. I can't read it.

Comment: Looks like  you've checked most of the obvious things. Did you get the ATSAMD21G18A  chip from a reputable source?

Comment: Suggest comparing it to the closest dev board schematic that can be found.  Also see if the chip has any stepping/revision/silicon eratta documents.

Comment: The Schematic should be more or less the same as on the Arduino MKR1310. The Chip is from Digikey, so I’m not worried about authenticity.

Comment: Double check your part number and footprint/schematic symbol - very easy to get this messed up. Placement and selection of the bypass capacitors is fairly critical. I got involved in diagnosing a poor pcb layout that used a sam21l and it came down to this.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a lot of searching, i found the problem.

And of course it's a stupid fault in my schematic. You can barely see it on the screenshot, but the SDA and SCL lines for the JTAG were switched.

Learning:

- Don't switch these lines
- Post better screenshots

Thanks for all your help.
I'll keep the question up, in case anyone has the same issue sometimes.